# Running a .vbs from a .bat?

Tags: vbscript, batch-file

I have been trying to run x.vbs with my test.bat, my x.vbs is supposed to replace text in another file so I will have to put in 2 parameters when executing it.
It works fine when I execute it in cmd:

```
cscript x.vbs "Text.txt" "1" "2"
```

(it will replace all 1's in Text.txt with 2's)

I have looked around and haven't found anything that would fit my needs.
Btw, I am very new with .bat and .vbs.

I am trying to replace a symbol that looks like a arrow that I get from merging 2 files. And When I use the arrow on the "1" spot. I get an error about (translated from swedish) "wrong matrix index" " " "2" is not a commando"

It works when replacing the arrow with a 1, but it's the arrow I want to replace.

What should I type in the batch-file to run the vbs?

Comment: If it works fine in cmd, then whats the problem using it in batch?

Comment: You didn't ask a question here.

Comment: I don't know what to write in the batchfile

Answer (score 0):

You can escape special characters with the "^" character:

```
 cscript x.vbs "Text.txt" "^>" "2"
```

http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/ntcmds_shelloverview.mspx?mfr=true

Comment: Didn't work, it's not that arrow either it's like a real arrow. I get it from:
copy a + b c

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean from "copy a+ b c". Can you clarify? Also, can you post the Swedish error message?

Comment: when I do the command:
copy a + b c
that merges a and b and creates c but it also adds a little arrow I want to remove, error message:
\x.vbs(6, 1) Körningsfel i Microsoft VBScript: Felaktigt matrisindex

" "2" är inte ett internt kommando, externt kommando, program eller kommandofil.

When I use the ^ it skips both the arrow and the " after it.

Comment: @Jontis: The arrow you can see as a result of `COPY a + b c` is likely the `^Z` or `\0x1A` character. You can avoid it by trying the `COPY /B a + b c` command instead.